# How i can create a canvas circle with arcs with images inside

Tags: canvas, roulette-wheel-selection

I have to do a roulette wheel like http://bramp.net/javascript/lunchwheel.html but in the colors arcs with numbers i need to put images, can i do that?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Why not share your code so we can take a look at it and see where you need to make the changes. A fiddle would be great bonus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we use paths and clipping we can do this easy

## [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/powerc9000/2Y3VK/)

we create a path with lines and arc then clip that path and draw the image where it needs to be. Remember to save and restore your canvas. because clip will clip all subsequent draws and fills to the path you made.

```
//This is for only one section of the circle and needs to be repeated 
//for all slices.
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var img = document.createElement("img");

var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
img.src="your-image"
img.onload = function(){run()}
function run(){
    ctx.arc(200,200,150,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(200,200);
    ctx.lineTo(350, 200);
    ctx.arc(200,200,150,0,Math.PI/2);
    ctx.lineTo(200, 200);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.save();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(img, 200,200);
    ctx.restore();
}
```